# How does web server lists files in absence of index files in the directory

Tags: apache, browser, nginx, webserver

How do I customize the list that web server does in absence of `index.*` file in the web root or its child directory, if we do not put any index files in the web root directory and the directory has the read permission?

Comment: in absence of index file we can see list of files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the page to show for a directory url with the `index` directive, it doesn't need to point to something called index.*, might just as well be `whatever.html`. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index for details

or you can set `autoindex on` to give a generated file/directory listing, you can use the `autoindex_exact_size` and `autoindex_localtime` to further customize that listing. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html for details

3th option, if your nginx is compiled with it, is the `random_index`, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_random_index_module.html for details.

NOTE: to find out if your nginx is compiled with the needed `--with-http_random_index_module` option use the command `nginx -V`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what webserver you are using.

In case of **Apache**, direcory indexes handled by a module called [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

When you want to customize the directory listing, then you have to know that Apache need three 'view' files:

- The Header — by default automatically generated by Apache The
- Directory Listing — necessarily generated by Apache
- The Footer — referred to as the “Readme” file

The Header and Footer parts are basically written in plain HTML. The directory listing is generated by Apache but you can apply CSS on it..

The whole thing is a rather long story, so what I can suggest is a well written article with the details about this 'directory listing customisation':

[Better Default Directory Views with .htaccess](http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/)